# position of the floor number in a US address

Tags: forms-of-address

Should the floor number such as "1st fl." go right below the recipient's name?

Or should it be placed on the same line as the street number, above the zip code?

Comment: I must ask how you know someone's address, but not their address as written. I suppose you could have been told it over the phone, in which case you'd at least know the order of the words, even if not the position of linebreaks.  It is more common to get the address from a written source, either from the return address of a letter, or from filling out a form, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If your query is not about the US, then this is not for you. Conventions differ depending on the country.

As here, but use FL instead of APT, and notice the spaces before and after the # symbol.

[image]

[Secondary Address Unit Designators (US Postal Service)](https://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28c2_003.htm)